# How can I refresh a ListBox to display latest data in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox

I populate a ListBox in a page with some data from a webservice, a list of comment replies. On that same page is a textbox and a post button that allows users to post a reply to a comment while on the RepliesPage. When I run the app and post a reply, the List isn't updated immediately, until I navigate away from the page and navigate back to the page will I see the new reply added to the List. How do I get around this?.
Page's XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="CeFlix.Views.RepliesPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:cimbalinoBehaviors="clr-namespace:Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Behaviors;assembly=Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit"
xmlns:cimbalinoHelpers="clr-namespace:Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Helpers;assembly=Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Background"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:UserControl="clr-namespace:CeFlix.UserControls">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarBehavior>
        <cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="postReply"
                                                         Text="post"
                                                         IconUri="/Assets1/AppBar/send.text.png"
                                                         IsEnabled="True"
                                                         Command="{Binding UserSubmitReplyCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <!--<cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="home"
                                                         Text="home"
                                                         IconUri="/Assets1/AppBar/basecircle.png"
                                                         IsEnabled="True"
                                                         Click="home_Click"/>-->
    </cimbalinoBehaviors:ApplicationBarBehavior>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="postReply" 
                                        IconUri="/Assets1/AppBar/send.text.png" 
                                        IsEnabled="True" Text="Post"
                                        Click="UserSubmitReplyCommand"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#0C426B">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel  x:Name="TitlePanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ContentHeaderStyle}" Height="72">

        <Button  Command="{Binding Path=ClickShowPopUpCommand,Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Height="65">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/Images/logo.png" Height="45" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="REPLIES" Margin="20,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" Foreground="#0C426B" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe WP Black"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" >

        <ListBox x:Name="lbxReplies"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ReplyList,Mode=TwoWay}"
             Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
             >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding profile_pic}"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>

                        </Ellipse>
                        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5"/>
                        <StackPanel   Grid.Column="1">

                            <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontSize="16" Text="{Binding username}" Foreground="#FFF8DE7E" FontFamily="Consolas" />

                            <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                                        FontSize="16" Text="{Binding comment}" 
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        TextOptions.DisplayColorEmoji="True"
                                        TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated"
                                        TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Consolas" />

                        </StackPanel>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBox x:Name="replyTextBox" 
                 Width="475" 
                 Text="{Binding Message,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 TextChanged="replyTextBox_TextChanged"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 GotFocus="replyTextBox_GotFocus">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/watermark2.png"/>
            </TextBox.Background>
            <TextBox.InputScope>
                <InputScope>
                    <InputScopeName NameValue="Text" />
                </InputScope>
            </TextBox.InputScope>
        </TextBox>
        <
    </StackPanel>
    <UserControl:DataLoading x:Name="loaderForReplies" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Visibility="{Binding LoaderForReplyVisibility}" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

       string parameter = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];
        BaseViewModel.SelectedCommentID = parameter;


    }
    private async void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        await repliesViewModel.GetReplyList();

        this.DataContext = this.repliesViewModel;
        lbxReplies.ItemsSource = null;
        lbxReplies.ItemsSource = repliesViewModel.ReplyList;
    }
```

And this is the ViewModel code

```
using CeFlix.Common;
using CeFlix.Entities;
using CeFlix.OtherEntities;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace CeFlix.ViewModels
{
    public class RepliesViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        #region Properties
    private UserStatusData userStatusData;
    public UserStatusData UserStatusData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.userStatusData;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref userStatusData, value);
        }
    }

    private string message;
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return message;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref message, value);
        }
    }

    private Visibility replyListControlVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility ReplyListControlVisibility 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.replyListControlVisibility;
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref replyListControlVisibility, value);
        } 
    }
    private Visibility userReplyPopUpOpen;
    public Visibility UserReplyPopupOpen 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.userReplyPopUpOpen;
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref this.userReplyPopUpOpen, value);
        } 
    }

    private Visibility loaderForReplyVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility LoaderForReplyVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.loaderForReplyVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.loaderForReplyVisibility, value);
        }
    }

    private Visibility signInPopUpVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility SignInPopUpVisibility
    {
        get
        {
            return this.signInPopUpVisibility;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.signInPopUpVisibility, value);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Reply> replyList;
    public ObservableCollection<Reply> ReplyList
    {
        get
        {
            return replyList;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.replyList, value);
        }
    }

    private ReplyDetails replyDetailsData;
    public ReplyDetails ReplyDetailsData 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.replyDetailsData;
        }
        set 
        { 
            SetProperty(ref this.replyDetailsData, value);
        } 
    }

    // Comment
    private CommentDetails comment;
    public CommentDetails Comment
    {
        get
        {
            return this.comment;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.comment, value);
        }
    }

    private Comment selectedComment;
    public Comment SelectedComment 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.selectedComment;
        }
        set 
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.selectedComment, value);
            if (value != null)
            {
                BaseViewModel.SelectedCommentID = this.selectedComment.id;

                this.GetCommentDetail();
                this.GetReplyList();
            }
        } 
    }

    private CommentDetails commentsDetailsData;
    public CommentDetails CommentsDetailsData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.commentsDetailsData;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.commentsDetailsData, value);
        }
    }

    private CeFlix.Entities.Detail videoDetail;
    public CeFlix.Entities.Detail VideoDetail
    {
        get
        {
            return this.videoDetail;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.videoDetail, value);
        }
    }

    private CeFlix.Entities.VideoDetails videoDetailData;
    public CeFlix.Entities.VideoDetails VideoDetailData
    {
        get
        {
            return this.videoDetailData;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.videoDetailData, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #region Constructor
    public RepliesViewModel()
    {
        this.ReplyList = new ObservableCollection<Reply>();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Single Instance could be replacement for Singleton that I know of

    private static RepliesViewModel currentInstance = null;
    public static RepliesViewModel GetSingleInstance()
    {
        if (currentInstance == null)
        {
            currentInstance = new RepliesViewModel();
        }
        return currentInstance;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Delegate Commands

    private DelegateCommand goHome;
    public DelegateCommand GoHome
    {
        get
        {
            if (goHome == null)
                goHome = new DelegateCommand(GoHomeCommandClick);
            return goHome;
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand userSubmitReplyCommand;
    public DelegateCommand UserSubmitReplyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (userSubmitReplyCommand == null)
                userSubmitReplyCommand = new DelegateCommand(UserSubmitReplyCommandClick);
            return userSubmitReplyCommand;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void GoHomeCommandClick()
    {
        BaseViewModel.NavigationService.NavigateToPage(Entities.Enums.Views.DashboardPage);
    }
    public async Task GetCommentDetail()
    {
        try
        {
            string Api_Url = string.Format(Constants.LoadComment_API, BaseViewModel.SelectedCommentID) + "?timestamp" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
            if (BaseViewModel.HelperClass.IsInternet())
            {
                var response = await BaseViewModel.HelperClass.Get(Api_Url);
                var selectedCommentDetails = JSONHelper.DeserializeFromJson<CeFlix.Entities.CommentDetails>(response);
                // this.SelectedComment = selectedCommentDetails.Comments;
                foreach (Comment item in selectedCommentDetails.Comments)
                {
                    this.SelectedComment = item;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);
                MessageBoxResult msgResult = MessageBox.Show(Constants.NETWORK_ERROR, Constants.NETWORK_ERROR_TITLE, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (msgResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    await GetCommentDetail();
                }

                else
                {
                    Application.Current.Terminate();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
        }
    }

    public async Task GetReplyList()
    {
        try
        {
            // LoaderForReplyVisibility = Visibility.Visible; // add this later, it think it should control display of usercontrol for replying

            string Api_Url = string.Format(Constants.LoadCommentReplies_API, BaseViewModel.SelectedCommentID) + "?timestamp" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

            if (BaseViewModel.HelperClass.IsInternet())
            {
                var response = await BaseViewModel.HelperClass.Get(Api_Url);
                this.ReplyDetailsData = JSONHelper.DeserializeFromJson<ReplyDetails>(response);

                if (ReplyDetailsData.Error.ToLower() == "none")
                {

                    this.ReplyList = this.ReplyDetailsData.details.replies.ToObservableCollection();
                    LoaderForReplyVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);

                MessageBoxResult msgResult = MessageBox.Show(Constants.NETWORK_ERROR, Constants.NETWORK_ERROR_TITLE, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

                if (msgResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    await GetReplyList();
                }

                else
                {
                    Application.Current.Terminate();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();

        }
    }

    public async Task GetVideoDetail()
    {
        try
        {
            string Api_Url = string.Format(Constants.VideoDetail_API, BaseViewModel.SelectedVideoID) + "?timestamp" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

            if (BaseViewModel.HelperClass.IsInternet())
            {
                var response = await BaseViewModel.HelperClass.Get(Api_Url);
                this.VideoDetailData = JSONHelper.DeserializeFromJson<CeFlix.Entities.VideoDetails>(response);
                if (VideoDetailData.Error.ToLower() == "none")
                {
                    this.VideoDetail = this.VideoDetailData.Details.FirstOrDefault();
                    //  this.GetVideoViews();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);

                MessageBoxResult msgResult = MessageBox.Show(Constants.NETWORK_ERROR, Constants.NETWORK_ERROR_TITLE, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

                if (msgResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    await GetVideoDetail();
                }

                else
                {
                    Application.Current.Terminate();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
        }
    }

    private async void UserSubmitReplyCommandClick()
    {
        try
        {
            if (BaseViewModel.HelperClass.IsInternet())
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Message))
                {


                    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Constants.Reply_API);
                    webRequest.Method = "POST";
                    webRequest.UserAgent = "immtv.loveworldapis.com";
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestSubmitReplyStreamCallback), webRequest);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("First Enter Reply");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000);

                MessageBoxResult msgResult = MessageBox.Show(Constants.NETWORK_ERROR, Constants.NETWORK_ERROR_TITLE, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

                if (msgResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    UserSubmitReplyCommandClick();
                }

                else
                {
                    Application.Current.Terminate();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
        }
    }


    // settle down to analyze this method because it's the body of the POST for posting a reply
    void GetRequestSubmitReplyStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        try
        {
            string requestBody = "";
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);

            // requestBody = "email=" + BaseViewModel.UserEmailId + "&reply=" + Message + "&video_id=" + BaseViewModel.SelectedVideoID;
            requestBody = "commentID=" + BaseViewModel.SelectedCommentID + "&comment=" + Message + "&email=" + BaseViewModel.UserEmailId;


            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);

            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseUserSubmitReplyStreamCallback), webRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
        }
    }


    // and this too
    void GetResponseUserSubmitReplyStreamCallback(IAsyncResult calldatabackResult)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)calldatabackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(calldatabackResult);
            using (StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                UserStatusData = JSONHelper.DeserializeFromJson<CeFlix.Entities.UserStatusData>(result);

            }
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                if (UserStatusData.status == "OK")
                {
                    //  this.GetReplyList();
                    this.Message = string.Empty;
                    MessageBox.Show("Reply Added Successfully");
                    RepliesViewModel repliesViewModel = RepliesViewModel.GetSingleInstance();
                    ReplyListControlVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    repliesViewModel.GetReplyList();
                    ReplyListControlVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
            });

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                BaseViewModel.ShowErrorMessage();
            });
        }
    }




    #endregion

}
```

}

and this inside the BaseViewModel, which the RepliesViewModel inherits from

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried several things like calling ListBox.Items.Clear(), this returned a debugger error, I tried ListBox.ItemsSource = null and bind it again, still dint work. What do i need to do to trigger a refresh and update the data displayed in the ListBox immediately?

Comment: Firstly, you should try to empty the underlying collection,so that the listbox will get propertyChanged notification.Secondly, You should try isolating the list in a sample & test, since theres a lot going on here.

Comment: could you explain in more details?

Comment: check my posted answer

Comment: I think there is a bug in your GetResponseUserSubmitReplyStreamCallback method, when you create a new instance of a RepliesViewModel. Call only the GetReplyList() method

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem change your code behind just to set the data context in your constructor:

```
    public MyPageConstructor() // Your page constructor
    {
        this.DataContext = new RepliesViewModel(); // Or any other way how you create your view model
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string parameter = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];
        BaseViewModel.SelectedCommentID = parameter;


    }

    private async void ContentPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await repliesViewModel.GetReplyList();

        //this.DataContext = this.repliesViewModel;
        //lbxReplies.ItemsSource = null; *removed*
        //lbxReplies.ItemsSource = repliesViewModel.ReplyList;
    }
```

and on your `ListBox` bind the `ItemsSource`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbxReplies" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ReplyList}"
         Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
         >
```

**EDIT:** I think you may have a *bug* in your `GetResponseUserSubmitReplyStreamCallback` method:

```
RepliesViewModel repliesViewModel = RepliesViewModel.GetSingleInstance();

repliesViewModel.GetReplyList();
```

If your `RepliesViewModel.GetSingleInstance()` method creates a `new` instance then this code will do nothing useful.

If the `GetResponseUserSubmitReplyStreamCallback` method is in your page class then you probably want to only call

```
repliesViewModel.GetReplyList();
```

Comment: This didn't work, It was added to the service but the page didn't trigger any update of data. I navigated to a previous page and back to the page before i could see it updated....anymore suggestion?

Comment: It's in a View Model that's why I needed a new instance of it, I'm using MVVM

Comment: OK, but you are not doing anything with this instance. You should create only one instance in your page, and manipulate with this one instance only.

Comment: I had the same issues from the CommentsPage, what I did was that I created a Usercontrol to hold the ListBox in a Grid, and bound it to a visibility property in the view model for that page. when a user now post a comment, I set the visibility to collapsed, then get the commentlist and then set visibility of the user control to visible so that the ListBox is reloaded and it worked perfectly, but just that the method didn't work  for this page, it created additional bugs

Comment: So after setting this.DataContext = new RepliesViewModel(), how do i call the GetReplyList in the OnNavigated event?

Comment: You can have a private field named repliesViewModel, then write two lines: `repliesViewModel = new RepliesViewModel();` and then `this.DataContext = repliesViewModel;`. After that you can access your viewmodel from anywhere in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new kind of list inheriting from `ObservableCollection` (looks like you already have done that) :

```cs
public class MyItems:ObservableCollection<Item>
{
}
```

Also you need MyItemsInstance to comply with `INotifyPropertyChanged` "pattern"

```cs
public class YourViewModelClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public MyItems MyItemsInstance
  {
    get
    {
        return this.customerNameValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.customerNameValue)
        {
            this.customerNameValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
  }

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
  {
      if (PropertyChanged != null)
      {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }
}
```

Then you can fill up your list instance calling the service.

This works if your are using MVVM in the right way. so in your XAML you need to bind the list source with your list instance , I can see this part in your code.
Take a look to the `ItemsSource` property

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="lbxReplies" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsInstanceInModel}"
             Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
             >
<!--All other stuff-->
</ListBox>
```

If the binding is OK, once you modify `MyItemsInstanceInModel` contents or even if you assign a new instance the UI should be refreshed by itself.

Comment: all this things you said are exactly what i've done, and there is no event to trigger getting the new data from the service, that's just the problem despite implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: But just in case, the code you have posted doesn't have any binding with  `ItemsSource` property on `lbxReplies`. The problem you told us is tipically due to binding issues. Your code is only binding on new instances (INotifyPropertyChanged) but not on Collection changes: ObservableCollection/(CollectionBinding as itemsource). Could you upload part of your solution to check the whole XAML page ,  and the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add lbxReplies.Items.Refresh() after emptying the listbox(lbxReplies.Items.Clear() or lbxReplies.ItemsSource = null).
   **Or**
2. Since, lisReplyList is binded to lbxReplies. So, Call ReplyList.Clear() instead of lbxReplies.Items.Clear() or lbxReplies.ItemsSource = null.

Comment: where do I add this in my code? could it be in OnNavigated event of the page?

Comment: when you Post the reply. because it should get updated the moment something new is added to the list,so you need not to navigate & come back to see the changes.Also, I feel adding the new post to list is better than clearing the list & refill again with new post.